# Number grouping and minimizing the maximum absolute deviation

Tags: optimization

I have a problem for which I am trying to produce an efficient algorithm. I tried to do a literature search, but I kept getting results for similar problems, never getting what I really want. Could you point me in the right direction for putting a more mathy name to my problem so that I can do a literature search?

My problem: I am given a list of n rational numbers. I am then asked to group these numbers into k groups with $\frac{n}{k}$ elements in each, given that k is a divisor of n. Let the sum of the numbers in group i be $t_i$. Let the average of all $t_i$ be $t_{avrg}$. My objective is to minimize the quantity max$(|t_1-t_{avrg}|, \cdots, |t_k-t_{avrg}|)$